# Can I call Odahviing back to Skuldafn?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I am at the part where Odahviing takes you to Skuldafn. I am about to become over encumbered and need to get back home to store my stuff. Can I do that then come back by calling him and asking for a ride back?

Comment: Not a duplicate?  Linked question is about returning to skuldafn later on in the story whereas the OP is already at skuldafn and wants to get back to Whiterun

Answer (score 1):

no you cannot call odaving back , if i were you i would drop all of your least important things such as soul gems , maybe you even have a few dragonbones or dragon scales which you will not need , but if all of your stuff is important to you then you should carry on . there might be some perks so when you level up you can carry more . thats all i can tell you.

Comment: You can carry more if you level your strength, so if you are about to level, choose strength. Also, potions of strength work wonders when over-encumbered, they often last for 5 minutes, which should be enough to get to a town.